# In Python 3.7 ,Django3.1.1 ,Apache/2.4.46 (cPanel) getting ther error : AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'

Tags: python, django, cpanel, mod-wsgi, django-wsgi

I am new to deploying the Django project on cpanel.
My cpanel was on python 2.7 but my project need python3.7 so I have installed a separate version of python 3.7 on cpanel by following this tutorial https://sysally.com/blog/install-python-3-x-whm-cpanel-server/ .After successfully installing python 3.7 I followed this tutorial to server my project on cpanel https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/how-to-install-a-python-wsgi-application/
Firstly I was getting this error "ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi" which i have solved by adding my virtual environment path to wsgi.py file , now my project wsgi.py file looks like this

```
import os, sys

# add the virtualenv site-packages path to the sys.path
sys.path.append('/home/***/public_html/app/unltdenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages')


from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'unltdsample.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Now I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 369, in <module>
    app_module = load_app()
  File "/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 76, in load_app
    return imp.load_source('passenger_wsgi', startup_file)
  File "/home/umadmin/public_html/app/unltd/passenger_wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from unltdsample.wsgi import application
  File "/home/umadmin/public_html/app/unltd/unltdsample/wsgi.py", line 19, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
  File "/home/umadmin/public_html/app/unltdenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.utils.version import get_version
  File "/home/umadmin/public_html/app/unltdenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/version.py", line 71, in <module>
    @functools.lru_cache()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'
```

i have searched about it, what i found is that the problem is of wsgi python version mismatch. And by running this commands i can fix this issue

```
$ sudo apt-get remove libapache2-mod-python libapache2-mod-wsgi
$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

but when i run this command in terminal i get

```
"sudo: apt-get: command not found"
```

when i run this with yum i get

```
No Match for argument: libapache2-mod-python
No Match for argument: libapache2-mod-wsgi
No Packages marked for removal
```

i have also tried to install with `pip install mod-wsgi` in my virtual environment it installed successfully, but the error do not solved.
can any body helps me solving this issue..

System Details :

Python 3.7.0 (default, Sep 29 2020, 12:40:13)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]

Django Version :3.1.1

Server version: Apache/2.4.46 (cPanel)
Server built:   Sep 22 2020 19:31:16

Comment: you are still using python 2.7 as lru_cache method is implemented in python 3

Comment: I have installed all the libraries in python 3.7 in virtual environment, As in question i have shown the version of my python 3.7 to. And yes it is true that python 2.7 is also installed by default on cpanel and i think it is makeing any conflict, @iklinac can you suggest any solution?